# Multiple linkage - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following relations

A|B
B|C
B|D
I|J
J|B
K|M
M|N

I would like to obtain the consolidated relations as below:
A|B|C|D|I|J and K|M|N

I started going the route of Python dictionaries, and creating a key-value pair for each relation, iterate through and add a new value to an existing key if any of the values of a key match any of the keys. But I am unable to get good solution. Any help with ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: How are these mappings stored? Am I correct in my understanding that you basically want to be able to lookup an A value and get a J value?

Answer (score 2):

You are seeking the connected components of an undirected graph.  Do not reinvent the wheel; use `networkx`.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge("A","B")
G.add_edge("B","C")
G.add_edge("B","D")
G.add_edge("I","J")
G.add_edge("J","B")
G.add_edge("K","M")
G.add_edge("M","N")
print(nx.connected_components(G))
```

Answer (score 0):

The symmetric (reflexive) nature of your relationships is a good case for sets. You can extend a set using `update()`. Beware of object linking issues - you want to make sure sets get updated, not replaced.

```
Relations = """A|B B|C B|D I|J J|B K|M M|N"""

def parse_relations(relstr):
    rels = {}
    for pair in relstr.split():
        a,b = pair[0:3:2]
        print(a,b)

        if a in rels:
            rels[a].update((b))
        else:
            rels[a] = set((a,b))

        if b in rels:
            if b is a:
                pass
            else:
                rels[a].update(rels[b])
                rels[b].update(rels[a])
        else:
            rels[b] = rels[a]

    return rels

def group_relations(reldict):
    distinct = set()

    for relset in reldict.values():
        relstr = '|'.join(sorted(relset))
        distinct.add(relstr)

    return sorted(distinct)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = parse_relations(Relations)
    g = group_relations(d)
    print(g)
```